# Creating a master key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, database-security

I'm trying to implement an encrypted column as in this following [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx). I understand most of the code except for the very first line:

```
--If there is no master key, create one now. 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101)
```

When I run that on the AdventureWorks database on my local machine, the key already exists, which is fine; I got the example to run fine and encrypt/decrypt properly on my machine.  However in that code there is no mention of a `symmetric_key_id` of `101` any at any point.

Is `101` some kind of reserved ID for symmetric keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seen [HERE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1312/managing-sql-server-2005-master-keys-for-encryption/), the `symmetric_key_id 101` is the `id` for the `Database Master Key`.

The number of database master keys is limited only by the number of databases you have - you can have one master key per database and its id is 101.